# When string set to Double it equals nil

Tags: swift

So here is my problem.

Im trying to convert a label.text to a Double value (the label only contains numbers.) Since the value is not always set we declare it as an optional value and I therefore use the method:

```
if let
```

My code is:

```
if let firstvalue = Double(label1.text!){
label2.text = "\(firstvalue)"

}
```

However, label2.text either returns nil or doesn't show anything at all. 
The value of label1 is calculated in another ViewController (ViewController2). 
But it still has a value that pops up and is equal to label1.text.

I am grateful for any help, cause I'm really stuck. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure label1.text! returns a number and it doesn't have any spaces? I had the same problem; I was receiving " 2.5" instead of "2.5" (note the space before the 2).

Comment: I figured it out!! I had as you said accidentally pressed space before the values. Haha can't believe I've been stuck with this for four days and that was the issue. Thank you so much would never have figured that out on my own!!

Comment: Im glad to help! I just write it as an answer, mark it as correct so everybody can figure it out quickier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
let lblval = label1.text
if let firstvalue = lblval {
label2.text = "\(firstvalue)" or label2.text = firstvalue
}
```

You are trying to add two strings, i.e lbl1.text = "55" and lbl2.text = "5" result = lbl1.test + lbl2.text. 
Finally you receive result as "555". Instead of adding string, first you can typeCast it into Double, float so it will give desired result

**Example :**

```
     let lblval1 = Double(label1.text) or Int(label1.text)
     let lblval2 = Double(label2.text) or Int(label1.text)

        if let firstvalue = lblval1, let secondvalue = lblval2 {

            let result = firstvalue + second value
            print("Addition : \(result)")

        }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes that works, the thing is that since i have multiple labels I want to add, i need a Double, float or an Int.
When I add first value with lets say secondvalue label2.text shows both of them but not the sum of the addition. 
Do you have any ideas on how to solve that?
Thanks for your reply it really helped!!!

Comment: Check my edited answer. It will do addition of two labels.

Comment: So heres the thing, I've tried all of your answers.
They all seem to work, since they don't return the nil and the application doesn't crash. 
However, nothing happens when the button is pressed, it seems like the: if let statement doesn't go through, like the firstvalue isn't = Double(label1.text!).
Thanks again for all your help, I'm very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, first make sure your steing doesn"t have any space or letter. It is not the same:

```
let num1 = String(" 2.5") //will crash
let num2 = String("2.5") //will work
```